# PHP Countdown Timer

Tags: php, javascript, timer, countdown

Is it possible to create a timer using PHP so that after 60 seconds it does something. So it actually shows you a countdown from 60 to 0. I would refresh the div so it actually looks like it's counting down. I don't mind using JavaScript but I want to run the timer only when the $_GET variable is = to something.

For either option, can anyone help?

For now, I'm using this code I got from EpicSoftworks on Youtube but the problem with this code is that you have to specify the timestamp you want to use.

```
$future = -2211753540;
$current = time();
$difference = $future - $current;

$minutes = floor($difference/60);
$r_seconds = floor($difference - ($minutes = 60) );

echo '<h2>' . $minutes . ' - ' . $r_seconds . '</h4>';
```

Comment: write some code first, update your post, then we can help

Comment: PHP is server side code. It would be pointless to make a call to the server every second to just countdown by 1. Use javascript and refresh or do something after the count

Comment: Whatever you end up with, careful with PHP's `max_execution_time`

Comment: use javascript, it's better for this case

Comment: I think that this is the right exercise for you to learn about the singleton pattern, since you want to do something with javascript

Answer (score 3):

use PHP to get the variable from the URL and then use javascript for the rest. Create a function that will run a loop 60 times. Inside that loop create a setTimeOut that will do something with a 1000 (1 second) timeout.

Comment: while in javascript, you wont make useless trafiic to the server